# LoDash 4.2.1 + Typescript: Error TS2403 ("subsequent vars must have same type")

Tags: typescript, lodash, definitelytyped

I am using `Webpack`, `DefinitelyTyped` and `Lodash` 4.2.1 (with TSD files loaded). When I attempt to run the following code:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

I get the following error:

> error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'LoDashStatic'.

Comment: This seems like an error in the library definition.

Comment: I belve so https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/7903

Comment: any updates of this?